# deduct price of sell on a new date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an item with sell by day, on the next day(with a select) I want to deduct the half of the sell and 1/3 of rest of days.

example: I have chocolate bar on day `1/1/2016` was sell `6 times`,
if I select the chocolate in 2/1/2016' I want the sell to be 3 ( half the ammout 6/2=3) , and if i select the chocolate in 3/1/2016 and onward I want the sell to be 2( 1/3-quarter- of the amout)

Another real example:

I have the following table :

```
create table ex_item ( id number(5) , name varchar2 (100) , sell number(4), date_added date)
```

In have the following result, I am getting the normal sell order:

```
SELECT * FROM ex_item WHERE DATE_ADDED >=TO_DATE('1/1/2016','DD/MM/YY')  ORDER BY SELL DESC
```

[image]

the Below is my desire output , select that deduct half of the old sell when its new date

The sell of Chocolate bar when added was 25, on the next day it was deduct half =12.5 however because of rounding its 13.
Is it possible to have such result

[image]

edit

[image]

Comment: How are you defining next day? The day after your search criteria or the day after the current date.

Comment: Calculate the number of days between your search date and the sell date and divide SUMM by it.

Comment: @Matt the day after my current day tomrow will be the next day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that result in `avg_sales_till_today` should be changing on daily basis, dividing the total sales by amount of days until the day of execution of the query.

**Edited the query**. From previous version it appears that casting `sysdate` with function `to_date()` was causing odd result, because of YEAR being `0016` instead of `2016`. Thus, the calculation result was negative and the final result 0. **This version should work**.

```
SELECT
  id, name, sell, date_added,
  ROUND( sell / ( to_char( sysdate - date_added, '999999D99' ) + 1.0 ) ) AS avg_sales_till_today
FROM
  ex_item
```

It's important that you add `1` value before division, because of operator precedence.

Comment: okay I will test it , but are you considring if it was old date , it will sum the quarter of it , not the half ?

Comment: `to_char` was causing error , I change it to to_date and the result was 0

Comment: If you run this at `2016-01-01` you will get `25`. On the next day `13`, On `2016-01-03` you get `8`. Check now, i fixed it a little bit.

Comment: I am selecting your query but its giving me wrong values check my edit please

Comment: the result of this select :  select to_date(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') - to_date('01/01/2016','DD/MM//YYYY') + 1.0 from dual  is -730482

Comment: select to_date(sysdate ,'DD/MM/YYYY') from dual = 05/01/2016

Comment: @Moudiz I've found the bug. Edited my answer. Check it out now :)